# How to play You tube video in android native Application through video view?

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to play YouTube in Native Android App.
This is My code But I got the result like Can't Play this video, So can you please help what is wrong in that code

```
public class Youtubeplay extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                "Loading Video wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA7Kkhv30WA";
            videoUrl = getUrlVideoRTSP(url);
            Log.e("Video url for playing=========>>>>>", videoUrl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Login Soap Calling in Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String getUrlVideoRTSP(String urlYoutube) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
            URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(connection
                    .getInputStream());
            Element el = (Element) doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList list = ((org.w3c.dom.Document) el)
                    .getElementsByTagName("media:content");// /media:content
            String cursor = urlYoutube;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = list.item(i);
                if (node != null) {
                    NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                    HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
                        Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                        maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                    }
                    if (maps.containsKey("yt:format")) {
                        String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                        if (maps.containsKey("url")) {
                            cursor = maps.get("url");
                        }
                        if (f.equals("1"))
                            return cursor;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Get Url Video RTSP Exception======>>", ex.toString());
        }
        return urlYoutube;
    }

    protected String extractYoutubeId(String url)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        String id = null;
        try {
            String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
            if (query != null) {
                String[] param = query.split("&");
                for (String row : param) {
                    String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                    if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
                        id = param1[1];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (url.contains("embed")) {
                    id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
        }
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        mc.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I am not an android developer, so I can't help you fix your problem. However, as a general tip, you need to provide more information in your question. You have told us what you are trying to do, however we need more information about what is going wrong. Also posting your entire class is very unhelpful. You need to narrow down exactly what is causing the problem and only post the problem code.

Comment: it seems duplicate questions..as u new to stackoverflow I think you dont know the rules here..google with proper keywords, you can find solution..People may vote down for duplicate questions..Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you.

Here code is your videoid ex:- 6HnoB8lD3AE

**Write in Async Task.**

```
private String getRstpLinks(String code){
String[] urls = new String[3];
String link = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + code + "?alt=json";
String json = getJsonString(link); // here you request from the server
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    String entry = obj.getString("entry");
    JSONObject enObj = new JSONObject(entry);
    String group = enObj.getString("media$group");
    JSONObject grObj = new JSONObject(group);
    String content = grObj.getString("media$content");
    JSONObject cntObj = new JSONObject(group);
    JSONArray array = grObj.getJSONArray("media$content");
    for(int j=0; j<array.length(); j++){
        JSONObject thumbs = array.getJSONObject(j);
        String url = thumbs.getString("url");
        urls[j] = url;
        Log.d(TAG, url);
        //data.setThumbUrl(thumbUrl);
    }


    Log.v(TAG, content);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    urls[0] = urls[1] = urls[2] = null;
}
return urls[2];

}
```

getJsonString() method.

```
public static String getJsonString(String url){
Log.e("Request URL", url);
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet     request = new HttpGet( url );
HttpEntity entity = null;
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    if( response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 ){
        entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while( (line = br.readLine() )!= null ){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        br.close();

    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try {
        entity.consumeContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception = " + e.toString() );
    }
}

return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call this code in mainactivity.java

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                int loc = savedInstanceState.getInt("Loc");
                Log.i("Loaction: ", loc + "");
                uriYouTube = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
                videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
                videoView.seekTo(loc);
                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Log.v("onPrepared", "ok");
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                new RTSPUrlTask().execute(model.VideoUrl);
            }



private class RTSPUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = getRTSPVideoUrl(urls[0]);
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            startPlaying(result);
        }

        public String getRTSPVideoUrl(String urlYoutube) {
            try {
                String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                        .newDocumentBuilder();
                String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
                URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
                Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
                String cursor = urlYoutube;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = list.item(i);
                    if (node != null) {
                        NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                        HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
                            Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                            maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                        }
                        if (maps.containsKey("yt:format")) {
                            String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                            if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                                cursor = maps.get("url");
                            if (f.equals("1"))
                                return cursor;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cursor;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return urlYoutube;
            }
        }

        public String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
            String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
            String[] param = query.split("&");
            String id = null;
            for (String row : param) {
                String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
                    id = param1[1];
                }
            }
            return id;
        }
    }

    void startPlaying(String url) {
        uriYouTube = Uri.parse(url);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
        videoView.start();
    }
```

I hope its useful to you.in my project ,its working fine.